# Extract from XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to extract "UDF_B_ACCOUNT.*.TCH" from below XML data in SQL Server.

```
<jobrundeps>
    <dep id="14175632">
        <type>2</type>
        <jobdepid>7390</jobdepid>
        <override>N</override>
        <met>N</met>
        <filename>/u01/pbm_data/rxad/UDF_B_ACCOUNT.*.TCH</filename>
        <filetype>200</filetype>
        <fileextent>0</fileextent>
        <nodeid>128</nodeid>
    </dep>
</jobrundeps>
```

Comment: Hey, edit the question instead of writing info as comments.

Comment: @jarlh,edited info now.

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work? What research did you do to find out the solution? There are plenty of examples of how to do this out there; what didn't you understand about them?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have this XML as a SQL variable - XPath will get you the contents of the `<filename>` element:

```
DECLARE @Data XML = '<jobrundeps>
    <dep id="14175632">
        <type>2</type>
        <jobdepid>7390</jobdepid>
        <override>N</override>
        <met>N</met>
        <filename>/u01/pbm_data/rxad/UDF_B_ACCOUNT.*.TCH</filename>
        <filetype>200</filetype>
        <fileextent>0</fileextent>
        <nodeid>128</nodeid>
    </dep>
</jobrundeps>'

SELECT
    @Data.value('(/jobrundeps/dep/filename)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
```

To get the file name only (without the path also stored in `<filename>`) in T-SQL, you can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Data XML = '......';

WITH FileNameCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        FN = @Data.value('(/jobrundeps/dep/filename)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        RevFN = REVERSE(@Data.value('(/jobrundeps/dep/filename)[1]', 'varchar(100)'))
)
SELECT 
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(RevFN, 1, CHARINDEX('/', RevFN)-1))
FROM
    FileNameCTE
```

Comment: Yes, that works for this specific xml value but i have this column in sql as a variable  and for few rows only it will have values.  Can i mention like DECLARE @Data XML='jobrun_deps'(my table column_name)

Comment: @hari: do these column values with the XML look "the same", in terms of the structure of the XML (just with different values in the various XML elements)?

Comment: XML look will get vary in my column. It can have 3 possible structures. 1.Null value 2. <type>1</type>...3.<type>2</type> .Second and Third case depends on type ,whether it is 1 or 2.Should extract  from case 3 which will have have <filename> XML attribute

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 onwards.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<jobrundeps>
    <dep id="14175632">
        <type>2</type>
        <jobdepid>7390</jobdepid>
        <override>N</override>
        <met>N</met>
        <filename>/u01/pbm_data/rxad/UDF_B_ACCOUNT.*.TCH</filename>
        <filetype>200</filetype>
        <fileextent>0</fileextent>
        <nodeid>128</nodeid>
    </dep>
</jobrundeps>';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT null)) AS seq
        , value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT((SELECT @xml.value('(/jobrundeps/dep/filename/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)')), '/')
)
SELECT TOP(1) value 
FROM rs
ORDER BY seq DESC;
```

**Output**

```
+---------------------+
|        value        |
+---------------------+
| UDF_B_ACCOUNT.*.TCH |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thnq @ Yitzhak Khabinsky

Comment: @ Yitzhak Khabinsky .XML look will get vary in my column.It can have 3 possible structures. 1.Null value 2. <type>1</type>...3.<type>2</type> .Should extract <filename>XML parameter from case3.

Comment: @hari, words are not enough. As I mentioned in the comments to your question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example, i.e. ##1-4